# Water leak detection - long drive way

Tags: plumbing, leak

My dad needs to repair a water leak on a property. This house has a long driveway (roughly 20 metres). But when he went there to have a look, there was no noticeable leak (water puddle etc). Bathroom & under the house have been checked thoroughly and there was no sight of any serious water leak. Currently there is about 0.8 ton of water lost per day due to this leak, which is not a small amount.

My question is that, is there any way we could detect where the water leak is without having to hire a plumber?

Is there any equipment that we could hire to find the source of the leak?

Comment: You're detecting the leak because the water meter shows exorbitant consumption? Where is the meter?

Comment: The metre is near the entrance to the property, at the side of the road, the very start of the driveway to the house. 0.8 ton is the extra water leaked outside of the normal consumption when all taps are turned off.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any special water finding tools.

"0.8 tons" is an odd way of measuring water, but that's about 200 gallons per day. Not exactly a lot for a normal household. How exactly have you arrived at that number? According to the USGS typical consumption is around 100 gallons per day per person. 200 gallons is about what you would get if you left a garden hose running for half an hour. If there were a leak in your water service line I am not sure you would notice.

Finding the leak may be tough. A leaking fixture (e.g. a constantly running toilet) could easily leak that much water. If you have access to the water meter you could shut off the water at the entrance to the house and see if it continues to spin... that would tell you if the leak is inside the house or in the yard.

Comment: I could add that if there is a singular water line that enters the dwelling and is accessible and does not have a shut off valve, now would be a good time to install one. First a shut off valve is essential to water leak isolation as mentioned by @HenryJackson. Secondly the valve is essential for cases of a unexpected leak happening inside the dwelling and you are in need of a very quick shutoff.